# Predefined box for automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, automata

I got from my university for my paper a predefined way of displaying automata and figures in general. Now I got the problem, that they don't really adjust to the margins of the paper. I want the figures to be as large as the text below at the sides, but I don't know how to adjust them. It would be really nice, if someone could help. So actually, I just want to make the box a little bit smaller in width.

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,arrows,automata,positioning,shapes,snakes} %graph properties
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llXll}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{} \\
& \multirow{2}{*}{Automaton} & & & \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5} \addlinespace[1.2mm] \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5} 
\multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth+7\tabcolsep}|}{
\begin{center}\underline{\textit{Automaton:}} $S= \{ S0, S1, S2, ... \}, M = \mathbb{N}, I= S0$ \end{center}
}\\
\cline{1-5} 
\multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth+7\tabcolsep}|}{
\begin{center}
%\scalebox{0.75}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 

   \node[state,initial,initial text={/ -}] (S0)   {S0}; 
   \node[state] (S1) [right=3cm of  S0] {S1}; 
   \node[state] (S2) [right=3cm of S1] {S2};
   \node[] (S3) [right=3cm of S2] {...};

   \path[->] 
    (S0) edge  [loop above] node [align=center]  {m / m} (S0)
    (S1) edge node [align=center]  {m / m} (S0)
    (S1) edge  [loop above] node [align=center]  {m / m} (S1)
    (S2) edge  node [align=center]  {m / - } (S1)
    (S2) edge  [loop above] node [align=center]  {m / m } (S2)
    (S3) edge  node [align=center]  {m / - } (S2);
\end{tikzpicture}  \\ %} 
\end{center}
} \\
\cline{1-5} 

\end{tabularx} 
\caption{Automaton}
\label{split}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  - Try `\multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr0.8\textwidth+7\tabcolsep}|}` instead of `\multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth+7\tabcolsep}|}` (2x)

Comment: Hi there, I just tried that and it only moves the figure inside the box to the left, but the size of the box does not change. Have you changed anything else in the code or have I missed out on something?

Comment: I confirm that what @Bobyandbob suggests works on my TeXLilve 2018 distribution. Did you modify *both* `\dimexpr` statements?

Comment: I didn't. Now it works. Thanks so much to both of you!